# Configure webapp on PWS to use SSL Service rather than HTTP

Tags: https, cname, namecheap

I have an application running on Pivotal Web Services that has 2 Front End components. I have added the Pivotal SSL Service and added a wildcard SSL certificate for my domain `mysite.io` and was given an "SSL Alias" that I was told to use in my registrar. My SSL Alias is : `mysite.io-353e6df7.ssl.run.pivotal.io`.

I have followed the instructions and put the CName value in my registrar (Namecheap), but the URL still goes to a non-ssl domain. I am trying to access my UAA instance via SSL for example. Here it is defined with the non-ssl wildcard CName entry and my CName entry for SSL.

[image: Cname Entries]

How do I get `*.uaa.mysite.io` to be over HTTPS?

Comment: HTTPS versus HTTP is a protocol change. Pointing a domain name to another cannot effect a protocol change. DNS only ties a domain name to a routable IP address. You will have to explicitly use https:// before your domain name or redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Seems that the cert is invalid when I manually go to HTTPS. The alias I have above doesn't seem to redirect to anything either.

Comment: DNS does not redirect. It is designed to only do one thing. Tie domain names to IP addresses. You will have to create any redirect on your web server.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file to redirect to https

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I don't have access to `.htaccess` in the Java build pack for Cloud Foundry.

Comment: If it is a Java app you can configure it to redirect to HTTPS in the web.xml: [How do you start a java servlet over https?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092649/how-do-you-start-a-java-servlet-over-https)